# How to change the blue color of selected datagrid rows

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Well, I have seen this code to do that:

```xml
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

        <Setter Property="Background">                        
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ucComponentesColorFilaMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="dgdComponentes" Path="ItemsSource" />
                    <Binding ElementName="dgdComponentes" Path="SelectedItems" />
                    <Binding ElementName="CurrentItem" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Really the code is the style trigger, the setter property is for other cases, but I add the code of this can affect to the result.

I would like  to change the selected row background, that by default is blue, and I want to other color according to some conditions. For example, if a register is added, then if I select the row it would be green, if this row is unselected, it would be light green.

I am be able to change the color of the rows as I want, but when I select it, always is blue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try something like this maybe...

```
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
```

Comment: This is correct, the selected item background color is actually a system color, so you have to overwrite the SystemColor in your Resources. Typically I use `<DataGrid.Resources>` so this style only applies to the DataGrid, and not every selected item in the application. Also, I think you only need the `HighlightBrushKey`, but I can't remember. The `ControlBrushKey` shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to assign color of the row pro-grammatically

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=BgColor}"/>
```

Add the **BgColor** property to the object that is being bound to the grid. On your condition set **BgColor** (i.e if object is register then BgColor is "Green")

Comment: I can't add the property to the object because is an STE (an entity of entity framework).

But I think that this things, if it can be doing by code, it is possible to do it in axml.

Comment: You could always create a view model over your Domain Model (in this case your STE) with additional properties, required to render your view