# How to bind the DataGrid.HighlightBrush by row in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a datagrid and the rows are different colors depending on the status of the record in them (Valid are White, Problems are Gold, and Banned are Red).

The problem is when the row is selected they all turn a uniform color and it becomes impossible to determine the status anymore. I would like to bind the highlight color in a similar manner to this:

```
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Member, Converter={StaticResource MemberBackgroundConverter}}" />
                    <Setter Property="HighlightBrushKey" Value="{Binding Member, Converter={StaticResource MemberHighlightConverter}}" />                        
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

The first Setter above works. Is there a way to get the second one to work? Is there any way to set the HighlightBrush per row?

EDIT:
The following is what I've got working currently. I don't mean to suggest that this is the best way to go, simply that this way works.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionBackgroundColorKey" />

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionBackgroundColorKey}, Path=Color}" Offset="0.0" />
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.3" />
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionBackgroundColorKey}, Path=Color}" Offset="1.0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionTextColorKey" Color="Black" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectionTextColorKey}, Path=Color}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Converter={StaticResource ReservationBackgroundConverter}}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding IsNew, Converter={StaticResource IsNewForegroundConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Code:

```
    private void DataGridReservationsSelectionChanged(object argSender, SelectionChangedEventArgs argEvtArgs)
    {
        Reservation LocalReservation;

        ((SolidColorBrush) dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionBackgroundColorKey"]).Color = Colors.SlateGray;
        ((SolidColorBrush) dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionTextColorKey"]).Color = Colors.Black;

        LocalReservation = dataGridReservations.SelectedItem as Reservation;

        if (LocalReservation == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(LocalReservation.IsArrived)
        {
            ((SolidColorBrush)dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionBackgroundColorKey"]).Color = Colors.ForestGreen;
            ((SolidColorBrush)dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionTextColorKey"]).Color = Colors.Black;
            return;
        }
        //Is this Reservation a Problem?
        if (LocalReservation.Member.IsProblem)
        {
            ((SolidColorBrush) dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionBackgroundColorKey"]).Color = Colors.Goldenrod;
            ((SolidColorBrush) dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionTextColorKey"]).Color = Colors.Black;
            return;
        }

        //Is this Reservation Banned?
        if (LocalReservation.Member.IsBanned)
        {
            ((SolidColorBrush) dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionBackgroundColorKey"]).Color = Colors.Firebrick;
            ((SolidColorBrush) dataGridReservations.Resources["SelectionTextColorKey"]).Color = Colors.Black;
            return;
        }
    }
```

This approach allows me to have the rows unselected color set with each independent row and the selected color set with each independent row.

Answer (score 0):

If using a DataGridTextColumn you could specify the ElementStyle:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MemberCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Member, Converter={StaticResource MemberBackgroundConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

...

```
 <DataGridTextColumn ... ElementStyle="{StaticResource MemberCellStyle}">
```

The Background color will respect the binding regardless if the row is selected or not.

Update:

You can make use of a MultiDataTrigger and create 2 Conditions (1 for your status and 1 for if the row is selected or not). Here's an example creating the style in code (for both selected and not selected conditions) but it should be easy enough to convert to XAML if need be:

```
Style cellStyle = new Style( typeof( DataGridCell ) );
MultiDataTrigger triggerNotSelected = new MultiDataTrigger();
Condition dataCondition = new Condition( new Binding( "[STATUS]", [STATUSVALUE] );
Condition rowNotSelectedCondition = new Condition();
rowNotSelectedCondition.Binding = new Binding
     {
          Path = new PropertyPath( DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty ),
          RelativeSource = new RelativeSource( RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof( DataGridRow ), 1 )
     };
rowNotSelectedCondition.Value = false;

triggerNotSelected.Conditions.Add( dataCondition );
triggerNotSelected.Conditions.Add( rowNotSelectedCondition );
triggerNotSelected.Setters.Add( new Setter( Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Gold ) );

MultiDataTrigger triggerSelected = new MultiDataTrigger();
Condition rowSelectedCondition = new Condition();
rowSelectedCondition.Binding = new Binding
    {
         Path = new PropertyPath( DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty ),
         RelativeSource = new RelativeSource( RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof( DataGridRow ), 1 )
    };
rowSelectedCondition.Value = true;

triggerSelected.Conditions.Add( dataCondition );
triggerSelected.Conditions.Add( rowSelectedCondition );
triggerSelected.Setters.Add( new Setter( Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Khaki ) );

cellStyle.Triggers.Add( triggerNotSelected );
cellStyle.Triggers.Add( triggerSelected );
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. For example, the unselected row is LightRed so I want the selected row to be BrickRed. I want the color to change but still be useful to determine the status. The problem I'm having is the rows are different colors (red, green and blue hues) so the selection color needs to be different for each row.

Comment: Updated answer. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: If I could get the binding to work this looks most promising. This is what I got and it's not working:
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelectedProperty }" Value="true" />

The unselected is working fine. In fact, you don't even need to specify IsSelected=false.

Comment: You may want to try specifying the AncestorLevel and changing the Path to "IsSelected" instead of "IsSelectedProperty" ... Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsSelected}"

Comment: I tried both of those and the selected background is still not changing. I think the problem is that I'm not setting the correct property. See ["How to change the blue color of selected datagrid rows"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694022/how-to-change-the-blue-color-of-selected-datagrid-rows) for more information. I'll post a sample of what I have got working and see if we can edit that.