# WPF datagrid semi-transparent selected cells (like Excel)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selection

In Excel, the bluish background selection color appears to be semi-transparent, so the user can still see the true background color even when the cell is selected.  How can the same effect be achieved with the WPF datagrid?

In my particular case, the cell's `Background` color is also binded to the view model.  My initial impression is to use a trigger in the cell style:

```
  <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="????"></Setter>
      </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
```

Then somehow the `Value` should calculate to ... some combination of blue and the UnSelected `Background` color?  I tried using a brush of transparent blue, the result does not blend with the previous cell background color.

Comment: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: attempted solution added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have tried should actually work.

Look at this example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF0090FF"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}" Background="Purple">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#6F0090FF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

There is blue rectangle. With `Fill` property set to `#FF0090FF`. What you should notice is the fact that what you call `"UnSelected Background color"` is actually `Background` of `DataGridRow`.

And now... Background color of selected cell is exactly the same as `Fill` of that rectangle(`#0090FF`). I only changed `Alpha` to roughly 50%(`#6F0090FF`).  And what you see is something greenish as you would expect.

[image]

**UPDATE**

When you want to preserve `Background` of `DataGridCell` then you have to choose different approach. I would suggest to create one more layer in your `DataGridCell's ControlTemplate`

This layer... we may call it for example *"selectedCellVisual"* will be visible only when cell is selected.

So... we have to create `ControlTemplate` thus we have to change Style of `DataGridCell` from previous example.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="selectedCellVisual" Fill="#6F0090FF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="selectedCellVisual" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Now `DataGridCell` has red `Background` and when it's selected then semi-transparent blue rectangle *"selectedCellVisual"* is visible. Transparent blue and red on background makes final violet color.

[image]

You should pay attention to

```
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
```

It has to be there... because we didn't change trigger for `IsSelected` property which changes cell's background. 
It's defined in default style. It changes `Background` and `Foreground` properties. You can notice this in first example. Foreground is set white and there is one pixel wide blue line around cell.

Comment: So you're saying it blends with `Background` of `DataGridRow`... is it possible to blend with `Background` of each `DataGridCell`?  That is my current difficulty, the cells have different backgrounds, and I want that to be noticeable even when they're selected.

Comment: @Tekito no! that's not what I am saying. I am simply saying, that when you set background to semi-transparent color then it's set to semi-transparent color. Well and when you change background color of datagridcell from for example red to semi-transparent blue... you can't expect that you will see purple... simply because there is no red anymore. So I will update my answer to cover this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11694300/282694) answer, I've found a solution with overriding of system colors for data grid, e.g. add some transparency for system highlight color and use regular text color during highlight:

```
    <DataGrid>

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush 
                x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" 
                Opacity="0.2"/>
            <SolidColorBrush 
                x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
                Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextColorKey}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

    ...
```